# Jenkins-SonarRunnerInstallation - Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-agent

I have problem with Jenkins – Execute SonarQube Scanner Build Option.

**Our Environment details as follows:**

```
 - Jenkins controller Server OS: Ubuntu-12.04 LTS-64 Bit. 
 - controller Server Jenkins Version: 2.46.2 
 - SonarQube Scanner Plugin for Jenkins -Version - 2.6.1 
 - Build Type: controller and agent based.  
 - Agent Machine: Ubuntu-14.04-LTS (64-Bit)  
 - SonarQube Server Version - 5.1 (64-Bit)  
 - Sonar-runner version 2.4  
 - Agent Machine Java Version – 1.8
```

**Problem Description:-** I have defined the `sonar.project.properties` information under the “Analysis properties” category in Jenkins controller server itself, When I tried to execute the same through it fails with below errors.java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:

```
hudson/plugins/sonar/SonarRunnerInstallation$1 : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
Caused: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Failed to load hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation$1
```

Comment: You are probably targeting a newer version of Java than your project supports.

Comment: I have tried with java version "1.7.0_121" and openjdk version "1.8.0_111".

Answer (score 6):

The issue is because of Java version mismatch. From the Wikipedia Java Class Reference  you can fin all the codes:    J2SE 8 = 52,J2SE 7 = 51,J2SE 6.0 = 50,J2SE 5.0 = 49

This error is caused becaused you are using a lower JDK at runtime (probably 7) than 8 that is the one used to compile that version of Jenkins

Comment: Need to be sure  the Java version 8 is in your path when you launch Jenkins.

The server have both Java 7 and 8 installed.

Comment: Hi Denis, My Jenkins slave machine has below variables,

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH

Still it fails.

Comment: If you keep have this issue you can write a JenkinsFile to force set JAVA_HOME 1.7 for the test part and 1.8 for Sonarqube

Comment: Problem solved by adding the JENKINS_JAVA_CMD environment variable and pointing to Java-1.8 path on Node/Slave Machine.